# What's VTIMEZONE used for in icalendar? Why not just UTC time?

Tags: calendar, timezone, icalendar, rfc5545

What's VTIMEZONE used for in icalendar?

e.g. 1

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.12.3//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Shanghai
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0900
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19910914T150000Z;BYMONTH=9;BYDAY=3SU
DTSTART:19890917T000000
TZNAME:GMT+8
TZOFFSETTO:+0800
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0800
DTSTART:19910414T000000
TZNAME:GMT+8
TZOFFSETTO:+0900
RDATE:19910414T000000
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
TRANSP:OPAQUE
LAST-MODIFIED:20170305T083916Z
UID:gjo1burcjnsib4p2j8tbbv4hh0@google.com
DTSTAMP:20170305T083916Z
LOCATION:Cell Group
DESCRIPTION:
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Study Bible
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20170324T193000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20170324T213000
X-APPLE-TRAVEL-ADVISORY-BEHAVIOR:AUTOMATIC
CREATED:20160312T140632Z
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR
BEGIN:VALARM
X-WR-ALARMUID:9B47E27E-9063-417E-B488-409387A3201A
UID:9B47E27E-9063-417E-B488-409387A3201A
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19760401T005545Z
ACKNOWLEDGED:20161125T105826Z
X-APPLE-DEFAULT-ALARM:TRUE
ACTION:NONE
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

> From [iCalendar Documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5)
>
> VTIMEZONE: provides a grouping of component properties that defines a time zone.

### 1. What's the definition of VTIMEZONE?

Is a rule to describe winter time and summer time for a location?

### 2. What's VTIMEZONE used for?

I don't have to specify a VTIMEZONE component in icalendar object. Instead, I transofrm my local time to utc time, and export icalendar event.

```
# Before
DTSTART:20170324T113000Z
DTEND:20170324T130000

# After
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20170324T193000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20170324T213000
```

2.1 Does this make sense?  a icalendar object without VTIMEZONE

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.12.3//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
TRANSP:OPAQUE
LAST-MODIFIED:20170305T083916Z
UID:gjo1burcjnsib4p2j8tbbv4hh0@google.com
DTSTAMP:20170305T083916Z
LOCATION:Cell Group
DESCRIPTION:
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Study Bible
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20170324T113000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20170324T213000
X-APPLE-TRAVEL-ADVISORY-BEHAVIOR:AUTOMATIC
CREATED:20160312T140632Z
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR
BEGIN:VALARM
X-WR-ALARMUID:9B47E27E-9063-417E-B488-409387A3201A
UID:9B47E27E-9063-417E-B488-409387A3201A
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19760401T005545Z
ACKNOWLEDGED:20161125T105826Z
X-APPLE-DEFAULT-ALARM:TRUE
ACTION:NONE
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

2.2 If this makes sense, what's the usage of VTIMEZONE?

### 3. Consistence between VTIMEZONE and VEVENT

Take e.g. 1 for example.

```
....
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Shanghai                           <- Part 1
.....
END:VTIMEZONE


BEGIN:VEVENT
....
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20170324T193000   <- Part 2
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20170324T213000     <- Part 3
....
END:VEVENT
```

3.1. Must timezone in VEVENT be consistent with VTIMEZONE?

3.2 Can I use other timezone to describe time in part2 and part3?

e.g.

```
....
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Asia/Shanghai                           <- Part 1
.....
END:VTIMEZONE


BEGIN:VEVENT
....
DTSTART:20170324T193000Z   <- Part 2 UTC time
DTEND:20170324T213000Z     <- Part 3 UTC Time
....
END:VEVENT
```

Answer (score 38):

**1. What's the definition of VTIMEZONE?**

VTIMEZONE is used to store the specific rules for the UTC offset a timezone has at any given point in time (i.e. when it is daylight savings time and when it is standard time).

**2. What's VTIMEZONE used for?**

It's used when you want to format your various timestamps throughout the iCalendar under a specific timezone instead of UTC.

You might ask: **Why not just use UTC everywhere?  Wouldn't it be simpler?**  The answer is: timezones are needed because of **recurrence rules**.  If you have a repeating event, and that event crosses a daylight/standard boundary, you have to specify a timezone for that event.  If you just used UTC, the event's time would become incorrect once you passed the daylight/standard boundary.

**2.1 Does this make sense? a icalendar object without VTIMEZONE**

Your example is incorrect.

The DTEND property in your example is referencing a VTIMEZONE component that does not exist ("Asia/Shanghai").

```
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Shanghai:20170324T213000
```

An iCalendar parser will look at that TZID parameter, and then look for a VTIMEZONE component whose TZID property matches it.  Because your iCalendar object does not have such a VTIMEZONE, the iCalendar parser technically doesn't know how to interpret that date.  **The TZID parameter is merely treated as a unique identifier.  It does not have any meaning in and of itself.**

If you want a date to be formatted under a specific timezone, but you do not want to include a VTIMEZONE component in your iCalendar object, you can use a **global timezone ID**.  Global timezone IDs are different from normal TZID parameters because they begin with a **forward slash**:

```
DTEND;TZID=/Asia/Shanghai:20170324T213000
```

The downside to global timezone IDs is that the iCalendar specification does NOT specify how these IDs are supposed to be interpreted by the parser.  However, in practice, I would imagine that out of all the parsers that support global IDs, most of them probably treat them as Olson IDs.

**3.1. Must timezone in VEVENT be consistent with VTIMEZONE?**

The timezone(s) defined in the VTIMEZONE component(s) have global scope across the iCalendar object.  So any TZID parameter in a VEVENT must reference a VTIMEZONE component (unless it is a global timezone ID).

**3.2 Can I use other timezone to describe time in part2 and part3?**

Just because your iCalendar object has a VTIMEZONE component, doesn't mean you have to use it.  Your example is valid.

Comment: Very useful, the forward slash tip for the timezone made my day

Comment: No joke.  Prefixing forward slash for time zone is killer.  But, it doesn't pass the ical validator tool unfortunately. https://icalendar.org/validator.html

Comment: Helpful, thanks. So basically, if you don't use *recurrence rules*, you can leave out the VTIMEZONE block entirely? I see many commercial calendaring applications always include it, even when there are no recurrence rules present.

Answer (score 0):

From a programmer under time pressure...
VTIMEZONE is difficult to manage in icalendar.py

I took  the following shortcut:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import icalendar

mytz = pytz.timezone('<your timezone>')
timestamp = datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)

# ... < Lots of code there >
event.add('dtstamp',vDatetime(mytz.localize(timestamp).astimezone(pytz.UTC)))
3 --- < tons of code here >
```

And did the same for `dtstart`and `dtend`

Comment: RFC 5545 states that DTSTAMP "MUST be specified in the UTC time format" while DTSTART and DTEND may specify a TZID included in VTIMEZONE or be in UTC.